# Convert JSON curl to C#

Tags: c#, curl, solr, httpwebrequest

I have the following curl code:

```
curl 'localhost:8983/solr/sessions/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"Session_SessionId":"da7007e9-fe7a-4bdf-b9e4-1a55034cf08f","Session_HasComments":{"set":true}}]'
```

I am trying to convert to C#, but I am getting an error every time so unsure if my code is correct...

Here's what I have so far:

```
        string path = "http://localhost:8983/solr/sessions/update?commit=true";
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"Session_SessionId\":\"" + sessionId + "\"," +
                          "\"" + fieldName + "\":{\"set\":\"" + fieldValue + "\"}}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

It always seems to error () on this line:

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

The error i get is:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.","StackTrace":"   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Dave

Comment: What error are you getting? Is localhost:8983 active?

Comment: you should provide the error you are getting.

Comment: The error I get is: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.","StackTrace at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Comment: Yes localhost is definitely active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's that you have removed square brackets in your JSON content that you are streaming into request? Try adding the [ ] back to the start/end of data. Although the "BadRequest" is usually quite strict error that tells you that your HTTP request is malformed, your server may actually return that code also for other cases - like missing session id - which probably occurred here.

note the diff:

```
-d '[{"Session_SessionId":"da70.....
    ^ bracket
```

and

```
string json = "{\"Session_SessionId\":\"" + sessionId + "\"," + ....
               ^ no bracket
```

and the same at the end of data.
But, of course, that's just a guess. :)

Comment: Added the square brackets, in - no errors anymore! Thanks you, now to figure out why it's not updating...

Answer (score 0):

Your request cannot be understood by the server. Did you check the output of json variable. I believe the JSON string is not generating properly.

Why don't you use [JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340417.aspx) to create JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Your use the Update Handler with a JSON object will need to follow the JSON format outlined in  [Update JSON - Update Commands](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON#Update_Commands)

Comment: I believe I already follow this, the original curl works, I just need the same implmentation in C#

Answer (score 0):

As another user has suggested your JSON output does not match the CURL.  Try the following rather than typing the text.

```
var data = new[]
{
    new
    {
        Session_SessionId = "da7007e9-fe7a-4bdf-b9e4-1a55034cf08f",
        Session_HasComments = new {set = true}
    }
};

var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
```

Also, you are using the `using` keyword to write the data through, and attempt to handle response while inside the block - it probably does make a difference but it might be worth moving this outside this block.

Lastly, you may need to encode the data as a byte array.

Here is the code implementing the above suggestions.

```
string path = "http://localhost:8983/solr/sessions/update?commit=true";
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

var data = new[]
{
    new
    {
        Session_SessionId = "da7007e9-fe7a-4bdf-b9e4-1a55034cf08f",
        Session_HasComments = new {set = true}
    }
};

string json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
byte[] byteData = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(json);

httpWebRequest.ContentLength = byteData.Length;
using (Stream stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
   stream.Write(byteData,0,byteData.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
string respStr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine("Response : " + respStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [SolrNet](https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/). If you are doing this with Solr 4+, you need to download latest code and built it yourself, but that's very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Dave, it worked for me.

You were missing square brackets. Just replace respective line with below:

string json = "[{\"Session_SessionId\":\"" + sessionId + "\"," +
                          "\"" + fieldName + "\":{\"set\":\"" + fieldValue + "\"}}]";